# clone git repository into pycharm

Tags: git, github, pycharm

So Im working with the PyCharm IDE on my Mac and try to import this git repository. The instruction on the website say (https://github.com/jsfenfen/990-xml-database):

git clone this repository   git clone https://github.com/jsfenfen/990-xml-database.git   and     $ cd 990-xml-database

--> I guess, these instructions are meant for the Terminal. Git is already installed and I also have a Github account - PyCharm settings for both are done. What are all the steps now I need to do in my Terminal or PyCharm?

Comment: In the directory that you want your project to be in, run `git clone https://github.com/jsfenfen/990-xml-database.git`. This will download all the files from github to a folder called 990-xml-database. Then open said directory in Pycharm (File - Open...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to VCS - > Get from Version Control

[image]

You will get a screen which looks like this. Just enter your repository URL.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That did it